# Unity - switch scene by using the onClick function from button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: C#] I cant find how to switch scene using a button in Unity.
I tried it but there were errors strong text
The videos that I had seen were too old.

I added an object (scene loader) then I dragged it into the on-click of a button, then I tried to add the function "Next Scene" but i just isn't there.
I did it multiple times and also made a new project and did everything again.

Comment: What code did you run? What errors did you get?

Comment: C# and there where errors in the Object saying " The associated script can not be loaded. Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script " .

Comment: sorry for bad English :(

Comment: Is your class name the same as your file name ? Based on your image, those 2 should be called `SceneLoaderBB`.

Comment: You can’t call a script “next scene” it can’t have spaces in.

Comment: Show us the code for Scene Loader please

Comment: Did you added the `SceneLoaderBB` component to the `scene loader` object in your scene? Also (and I know this was probably a typo, but I'm just checking), if the method in the component is called `LoadNextScene` then it should show up in the button event inspector as `LoadNextScene` not `Next Scene`.

Comment: When you add code for examples, please write it directly in your question instead of using an image host - there are a lot of benefits to this, including the fact that it will never be lost from your question because the image host has removed the file.

Comment: add an empty game object to the scene... to that object add the script you just showed.  now drag and drop the object from the scene to the button events in the inspector... that should allow you to see the method in the drop down.

Comment: you also have to make sure you save the code file in your code editor

Comment: sorry Joe, but the code function in Stackoverflow didn't worked

Comment: Darkonekt, where can I find the code editor?

Comment: The code editor is whatever you use to edit your code...Most likely visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be solution for your answer

```
public void OnClickSceneChange(){
    int sceneindex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    if(sceneindex != SceneManager.sceneCount){
       SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneIndex + 1);
   }
}
```

use this method in button's onclick event

Comment: this does not answer the questions. he already has a method for it.

Comment: i have posted this answer before he changed his question you have seen question 2 days before so you can judge me on basic of this first check his previous question

Answer (score -1):

I know this is very late, but just in case you still need an answer, you need a `;` on `line 4` when you add `UnityEngine.SceneManagement`. I had the exact same problem, and I didn't notice the error until I saw your post, so thank you for helping me!